# jquery show hide problems using a select box/dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, mouseup

I have a word inside of a div. that's part of a drop down but the drop down is hidden, the specific focus is on "DC" right now... in the image below were looking at sales:

HTML:

```
<td class="edit">
<select class="touch" style="display: none;">
<option value="11">Rebuying</option><option value="12">Sales</option></select>
<span class="look">DC</span>
</td>
```

[image: before click it's just text]

After you click on the word "DC" a drop down select appears. Notice the class changed from edit to editing.

```
<td class="editing" data-oldvalue="13">
<select class="touch" style="display: inline-block;">
<option value="11">Rebuying</option><option value="12">Sales</option></select>
<span class="look" style="display: none;">DC</span>
</td>
```

[image: after clicking sales the drop down appears]

Here's my function for `show() hide()`:

```
//allow flipping between "look" and "touch" mode for all editable fields
        $('td.edit' + suffix).click(function(event) {
            //make this the only TD in "editing" mode
            event.preventDefault();
            back_to_look();        
            td_to_touch($(this));
        });

        var mouse_is_inside = false;

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('td.edit').hover(function(){ 
                mouse_is_inside=true; 
            }, function(){ 
                mouse_is_inside=false; 
            });

            $("body").click(function(){ 
                if(! mouse_is_inside) $('.touch').hide();
                back_to_look();
            });
        });

function back_to_look() {
    $('td.editing ,td.edit.new').each(function() {
        $(this).children('.look').show();
        $(this).children('.touch').hide();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('edit')) {
            $(this).addClass('edit');
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('editing')) {
            $(this).removeClass('editing');
        }
    });
}

function td_to_touch(td) {
    var theTouch = td.children('.touch');
    var theLook = td.children('.look');
    var oldVal = theLook.text().trim();

    td.addClass('editing');
    td.removeClass('edit');
    theLook.hide();
    theTouch.show();

    //save the existing value so it can be compared to when the "change" event is fired on the element
    td.attr('data-oldvalue', theTouch.val());

    if (theTouch.is('select')) {        
        theTouch.children('option:contains(' + oldVal + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
        theTouch.val(oldVal);
    }
}
```

The first part works okay, when i click on the word "DC" the drop down appears... and when i click outside the div back into the body it hides. That works fairly good, the problem is when the drop down select box is showing and i click on it to make a selection it disappears before i can make my selection because i'm using the `mouseup()` function.

I need people to be able to make a selection and than after that when they click outside of the div it disappears.

I've tried using .live, on(click, function()) and just about everything. Please any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**SYNOPSIS:** The drop down won't stay open so i can make a selection because i'm using mouseup().

Now, when i click on the text it's firing for both the drop down and the datepicker randomly pops up too.

```
 <td class="edit">
                        <input type="text" class="touch dtpick">
                        </input>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_est_date(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <input type="text" class="touch dtpick">
                        </input>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_due_date(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <input type="text" class="touch dtpick">
                        </input>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_next_date(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
```

It's being a bit quirky because of the dtpick class being touch as well. ack!

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating your issue?

Comment: It's nearly identical to this, although my dropdown doesn't stay open so i can make a selection. All the other functionality is the same. http://jsfiddle.net/TEyHC/10/

Comment: 1. i click on the text  2. after clicking the drop down appears 3. i make a selection from the drop down. 4. i click anywhere outside in the body and the drop down dissappears and goes back to the selected text.

Comment: step 3 is not functioning correctly atm. step 3 is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a `<select>` element, `.focusout()` will do just fine.

```
$('.look').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.touch').show().focus();
});

$('.touch').focusout(function(){
   $(this).hide();
   $('.look').show();
});
```

---

If it's firing multiple element with the same class, you just need a better selector. I noticed there are set of `'.look'` and `'.touch'` for each `<td>`. You can use `.siblings()` to find the element on the same parent `<td>` only.

```
$('.look').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.touch').show().focus().focusout(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.look').show();
    });
});
```

I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/WGR85/1/) as well

Comment: Thank you for looking at this, ill try it and respond back. I never thought about focusout().

Comment: That actually works really nice and functions exactly how i expected it too, the only problem is it's firing off the date picker which i have on the same page too. the class is similar.  I'll post the date picker code below everything else in my original post.

Comment: Hi cook, you just need a better selector to target the exact element. I've updated my answer, please check it out.